# R Programming Syntax

Tags: r, vector, syntax

I have two vectors: numbers1 and numbers2 with integer elements in them. I want to calculate the element ­wise products of n​umbers1​ and numbers2.​ For example, in numbers1, the first value is 3 and in numbers2 the first value is 2. What would be the syntax?

This reminds me of array elements in Java but I'm unable to conclude how to multiply them. I am new to R programming.

Comment: Maybe looking at `1:5 * 6:10` will help you figure it out.

Comment: This is the most basic type of operation in R. Nearly everything is vectorized. I strongly suggest you read a [basic R tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) (specifically [vector arithmetic](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic)) before you proceed with R.

Comment: Or the [r inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) which is not only filled with useful examples but a somewhat entertaining read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed that this is a very basic R question, but just in case a brief "cheat sheet" is helpful to OP or some other user:

```
A = c(1,2,3,4,5)
B = c(2,2,2,2,2)

> A * B
   [1]  2  4  6  8 10
> A + B
   [1] 3 4 5 6 7
> A / B
   [1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5
> A - B
   [1] -1  0  1  2  3
> A ^ B
   [1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

If you wanted to multiply, say, the first integer in A and B, you could do:

```
A[1] * B[1]
```

...or any combination therein.

For multiple integers in each vector, you'd do:

```
A[1:2] * B[1:2]
```

or

```
A[c(1, 3)] * B[c(1, 3)]
```

Comment: Hi Nancy, thank you for the post. I understand doing arithmetic with both vectors as a whole. I wanted to know the syntax for example, to multiply the first two integers of vectors A and B.

Comment: @sumaafaizy - you mean like `A[1:2] * B[1:2]`?

Comment: Got it. I added a few more examples. Does that help? Let me know if anything else is unclear.

Comment: ah! I get it now. It's like elements in an array index in java. In this case, instead of starting at 0, the elements start at 1. Thank you for your help, Nancy!

Answer (score 2):

In R the simple vector multiplication gives you element wise multiplication

`>a=c(1,2,3)`

`>b=c(1,2,3)`

`>a*b`

`[1] 1 4 9`

In addition
If you want matrix multiplication it will go like...

`>a%*%b`

`[,1]
[1,]   14`